# Why does push_back fail for unique_ptr of string vectors?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

The code below has a segmentation fault. When there is not a unique_ptr involved everything works fine.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto vect = std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>();

  vect->push_back("abc");  // Segmentation Fault.
  vect->emplace_back("abc");  // Segmentation Fault.

  return 0;
}
```

In case of this matter, I'm compiling using g++ 10.2 on Ubunutu.

Comment: You've created an _empty_ `unique_ptr`!  (Those `()` at the end of the line are the _unique\_ptr`_'s default constructor - not a held vector's constructor.)  Put something _into_ it, like, an empty vector (from the heap).  ("Empty" means null: It's not pointing at anything.)

Comment: Why are you trying to create a `std::vector` (or `std::string` for that matter) on the heap in the first place?

Comment: Well, @gph, if C++ compilers gave warnings for when a C++ programmer missed something obvious - well, it would sure keep the C++ compiler writers busy thinking them up!  There's a bunch of easy ways to hang yourself (and more difficult ways too...) ... that's why it's such an interesting and exciting language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a `std::unique_ptr` using its default constructor, so it is holding a `nullptr` pointer. You are not creating a `std::vector` object for it to point at.

Use `new` to create the `std::vector`:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto vect = std::unique<std::vector<std::string>>(new std::vector<std::string>);
    // or:
    // std::unique<std::vector<std::string>> vect(new std::vector<std::string>);
    vect->push_back("abc");
    vect->emplace_back("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

Or, in C++14 and later, use `std::make_unique()` instead of constructing the `std::vector` manually:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto vect = std::make_unique<std::vector<std::string>>();
    vect->push_back("abc");
    vect->emplace_back("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

However you really should not create standard containers in dynamic memory, unless you absolutely need to.

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string>> vect;
    vect.push_back("abc");
    vect.emplace_back("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re standard containers on the heap, the function is parsing a file with an unknown number of elements (string in this case, but not always). Despite how I presented the example (total bonehead moment) I'm using make_unique. I'm not a fan of the dynamic vector allocation, but I'm not sure how else to construct the unique_ptr. Totally open to ideas!

Comment: @gph "*the function is parsing a file with an unknown number of elements*" - that doesn't require the vector itself to be allocated on the heap, as demonstrated by my 3rd example.

Comment: Right, the vector is being passed back to the caller. I took another look and it will get moved if I return by value so yeah, that seems fine.

Comment: @gph yes, you don't need to allocate the vector dynamically, use move semantics instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your `unique_ptr` instance as follows:

```
using type = std::vector<std::string>;
auto vect = std::make_unique<type>();

vect->push_back("abc");     // No segfaults now
vect->emplace_back("abc");  // No segfaults now either

std::cout << vect->at(0) << std::endl;
```